# I need help learning to code python, can't find anything good

Tags: python, programming, educational

I have a decent understanding of python, however in order to advance I definitely need to learn.

I have tried to use wikis, youtube, etc and coding whilst reading/watching, but for me it just doesn't stick.

I then thought "I'll just do what I can and ask the community for help." (hoping to give back in future) but again, not a great experience.

Despite accurately conveying what my problem is, what I've tried, and what I need to fix, the forums I have used (particularly the python community on stackoverflow) have consistently landed so far from my question that several times I have rewritten my post to redirect the reader to the actual issue I have as opposed to "don't do it like that, use this module". The "that" they refer to is pretty much the entirety of python I know, and "this module" tends to be something that almost seems designed to scare off beginners.

Is there a forum where if I ask a question it will be answered? Is there (ideally free, but I can pay a little) software for PC or mobile that aids in learning more than just the basic python functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/)? For decades I have taught myself only from books. Recently I tried my first ever video course (for [Flutter/Dart](https://www.udemy.com/course/flutter-bootcamp-with-dart/)) and was ***extremely*** impressed. If they are all like that, I will never read another book again.

That one taught me to build a few apps, which gave me a few ideas. Udemy has [over 10,000 Python courses](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=python) - surely one can help?

Whatever you do, get a decent IDE - and there is none better than [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). The community edition is free, even for commercial use, and that's what I use at work.

Perhaps you need a hobby project? For less than $20 you can get some good hardware to play with. Perhaps a real work app, like reading sensors or controlling something, would spur you on?

I like to play with the [BCC Micro:bit](https://microbit.org/), which is simple enough, or the ESP32 - [M5Stack](https://m5stack.com/) is a great system for hardware newbies, and AdaFruit have  lots of good hardware for Python](https://learn.adafruit.com/welcome-to-circuitpython/what-is-circuitpython). Plus, of course, there is the Raspberry Pi (I prefer the Pi Zero W).

Look at Hackster for [ideas for projects](https://www.hackster.io/projects).

Does that help any?

Comment: I had never heard of udemy till now, gave it a look and my god! I look at that site and I see me getting a job in the development sector very soon. Thank you very much!

Comment: Wah ! I don't think that I ever made so much influence on anyone before. I sincerely wish you the best. Whatever you do, use PyCharm - I do professionally. Udemy is dirt cheap, and you can have a lot of fun with ESP32, BBC micro:bit, etc. Feel free ro ask further questions (even though they will be off-topic ;-)